# XCUITest selectPickerWheelValue Keeps looping forever until appium Stops it, I am not sure why

Tags: appium-ios

Hi I am learning Mobile App UI automation for both android and iOS, I am stuck trying to get a picker wheel to move a certain value (105). This is using the UIKitcatalogu App from Appium GitHub.

The function used to do so selectPickerWheelValue keeps looping forever and I am not sure why, below is my code:

```java
public static void wheelPicker(AppiumDriver driver) throws Exception {
    driver.findElement(accessibilityId("Picker View")).click();
    WebElement picker1 =  driver.findElement(iOSNsPredicateString("label == \"Red color component value\""));
    WebElement picker2 =  driver.findElement(iOSNsPredicateString("label == \"Green color component value\""));
    WebElement picker3 =  driver.findElement(iOSNsPredicateString("label == \"Blue color component value\""));

    WebElement []pickerL = {picker1, picker2, picker3};
    boolean desiredValueReached = false;

    for(int i = 0; i <3;) {
        while (!desiredValueReached) {
            HashMap<String, Object> pickerWheel = new HashMap<>(); //creating a hashmap to store pinch mandatory parameters
            pickerWheel.put("elementId", ((RemoteWebElement) pickerL[i]).getId());
            pickerWheel.put("order", "next");
            //pickerWheel.put("value", "100");
            driver.executeScript("mobile: selectPickerWheelValue", pickerWheel);
            if (pickerL[i].getAttribute("value").equals("105")) {
                desiredValueReached = true;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

[Video reproduction of the issue can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH8SA.gif)

The weird thing is I had a COMMENTED a line of code printing out the current pickerWheel value, when that line was deleted the function stopped looping , after playing around with different ways to fix this now it ALWAYS loops for ever, here is what I tried to fix this:

1- tried adding waits before the value of picker wheel is checked

2- Removed the commented print line, that only fixed the issue temporarily

3- Restarted Appium Server and build code again